# STRATO & Python connection to mySQL DB is not possbile

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

my Domain/Webspace etc is hosted by Strato (https://www.strato.de) and I am able to execute python scripts.
The script is working perfectly fine in the development env (Windows 10) - I am able to connect to the DB without any issues.

But within the strato env I receive the following error:
2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'rdbms.strato.de:3306' (113 No route to host)

Relevant Code:

```
....
import mysql.connector
....
try:
    db_link = mysql.connector.connect(
        host    = "rdbms.strato.de",
        user    = "xxxx",
        passwd  = "yyyy"
    )
except Exception as e:
    print("The error raised is: ", e)
    return
....
```

But I am unable to establish the connection to the database (error see above)....

Python version used:
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=8, micro=8, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

Any thoughts?

Many thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

after trying a lot of different approaches I found a solution (working for Strato).

Mistake was.
....
import mysql.connector
....

Working solution

```
....
import MySQLdb
....
try:
    db_link = MySQLdb.connect(
       <host>,
       <user>,  
       <passwd>,
       <database> 
    )
except Exception as e:
    print("The error raised is: ", e)
    return
....
```

Maybe this is helpful for someone...

Best regards....

Answer (score 0):

I am stuck at the very same point but cannot use your solution:

Which package did you install for `import MySQLdb` to work?
"mysql-connector-python (8.0.30)" does not offer this and I always come back to "MySQL-python (1.2.5)" browsing several sites - which does not help as it supports only Python2. I'm trying several different MySQL packages, none worked so far...

Or did you have to make any special settings at Strato?

Thanks a lot, Tobi

Edit: From my point of view this simply does not work as long as you do not order an explicit own server... see: https://www.strato.de/faq/hosting/gibt-es-bei-strato-einschraenkungen-bei-den-mysql-funktionen/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).